# MVC tabs faster page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a page that contains many tabs (5), and each tab when clicked loads different page with form fields and populates them.

I want to be able to load these pages faster when each tab is clicked.  What is the best way to load pages in MVC when a tab is clicked.  Should I be using partialviews vs. normal views?  Is there
a better way of doing this, to achieve the optimum page loads, like via ajax where no page refresh is needed?

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Ordx", new { id = orderid })">General</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Items", "Ordx", new { id = orderid })">Item</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Total</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Shipping", "Ordx", new { id = orderid })">Shipping</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Comment", "Ordx", new { id = orderid })">Comment/Note</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Preview", "Ordx", new { id = orderid })">Preview/Send Order</a>     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Yes, you may want to use ajax for this need. Partial views will be good to use for such dynamic content load. Also you may cache your views by parameters as we can hit the server only when the input changes.

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat. Have you bundled your CSS and JS? Have you optimized caching on IIS? Are you using separate sub-domains for the image payload and loading from a cookie-less domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try bootstap tabs.

By using partial views it is more faster to load and understand.